# How do you disable the Maximize button in MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, maximize, sdi

How do you disable the Maximize button/capability in an SDI application?

Comment: are you talking about a dialog or a SDI application ? you should edit the title.

Comment: I edited the title. Next time, pam, please use a descriptive short version of the question as a title instead of "MFC dialog question" :)

Answer (score 8):

For completeness:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    ModifyStyle(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 0);

    <etc...>
}
```

Comment: I prefer this to an external link that could be broken in the future.

Answer (score 5):

```
ModifyStyle(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,0,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);  // disable maximize
ModifyStyle(WS_MINIMIZEBOX,0,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);  // disable minimize
ModifyStyle(0,WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);  // enable maximize
ModifyStyle(0,WS_MINIMIZEBOX,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);  // enable minimize
```

try this, should be working

Answer (score 0):

You can see it here: [How to disable maximize in SDI application](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1581037)