# How to Remove/Disable Maximize button of CFrameWnd

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am beginner in MFC. I have created a window using MFC framework - CFrameWnd, CDocument and CView. For this window I need to disable Maximize button from system menu after window is created. But I am not able to find the solution for it. I have tried with below solution, but its not working:

```
  CWnd *poWnd= AfxGetMainWnd();
  HWND oHwnd = poWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
  SetWindowLong(oHwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(oHwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
```

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve it?

Comment: Do it before Creaetion in PreCreateWindow. 

Or leave the button as it is and just protect the application against switching to maximized state.

Comment: I think the reason is the same as in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486327/using-modifystyle-with-ws-thickframe-on-a-cpropertysheet-cdialog

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't do it before windows creation as I am using companies library. I will try to protect window from maximizing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906116/how-do-you-disable-the-maximize-button-in-mfc

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402297/creating-window-frame-without-maximize-button-and-without-resizing-options ; And I think, if it is possible, you have to do it in tour class' `CreateWindow` method, otherwise it would be too late.

Comment: I copied/pasted your code into existing project of mine & it works. Maximise button is disabled. So there's either some other problem or placement of where you're putting this.

Comment: Hi I have existing library which using CDocument, so I can't change that library. I want to disable maximizing functionality for one of my window created through that library. And that's why I am doing it after window creation.